# (ESP32) Cookie lost after page refresh only on safari

Tags: javascript, cookies, webserver, arduino-esp32

So I have created an authentication system for ESP32.
This is a really basic system where a user can enter the credentials on the webpage,
the server authenticates them and sets a cookie with a session id.
The webpage is refreshed after that, immidiately.

I list the relevant function for this:

**ESP32 Backend cookie set function**

```
void setCookie(AsyncWebServerResponse* response, const char* name, const char* value, int secondsFromNow) {
    time_t now = time(nullptr);
    time_t expirationTimestamp = now + secondsFromNow;

    // Convert the expiration timestamp to a formatted string for the "expires" attribute
    struct tm* tmInfo = gmtime(&expirationTimestamp);
    char expires[128];
    strftime(expires, sizeof(expires), "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT", tmInfo);

    // Set the cookie with the "expires" attribute
    char cookie[512];  // Adjust the buffer size as needed
    snprintf(cookie, sizeof(cookie), "%s=%s; expires=%s; path=/", name, value, expires);
    response->addHeader("Set-Cookie", cookie);

    printf("[Server] - Set cookie: %s\n", cookie);
}
```

This function prints out the following:

**Set cookie: sessionID=2B945041-3DF6-454A-BC37-2C72A0C46150; expires=Mon, 27 Nov 2023 10:36:14 GMT; path=/**

On the client side i just reload the page if the request was ok

```
form.addEventListener('submit', async function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if( isLoading ){return;}
    const username = usernameElem.value;
    const password = passwordElem.value;
    if( username === "" || password === "" ){
        return setError(lang.getWord("emptyInput"));
    }
    setLoading(true);
    const resp = await fetch("/auth/login", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            username: username,
            password: password
        })
    });
    setLoading(false);
    if( resp.ok ){
        setTimeout(() => {
            location.reload();
            //window.location.href = "/";
        },500);
    }else{
        return setError(lang.getWord("wrongUsernameOrPassword"));
    }
}, false);
```

**Tested on**

- Android chrome, firefox, opera ( All works )
- Windows chrome, opera, edge, firefox, brave ( All works )
- Iphone safari does not work. ( Yet to test other browsers )

When the page reloads the backend checks for the session id and logs in the user. If no session id found (or expired or changed), returns the login page.
On Iphone safari i always get the login page back.

**I have tried the followings**

- Set/unset path on cookie
- Set/unset domain on cookie
- Delay the reload on client side with various timeouts
- href to "/" instead of `location.reload()`
- Add/Remove last semicolon from cookie string

**Yet to try**

- Even longer delay on reload
- Other browsers on Iphone.
- SameSite attribute to none
- httponly attribute

There are a lot of issues with Safari on Iphone but this is the most frustrating. I have multiple bugs on Safari which works across all different platforms and browsers but Safari on Iphone. I don't know what apple developers are doing but it would be good if they would stop and just implement things the way others do. ( z-index on a page for example, haptic feedback on webpages etc... etc... )

**EDIT1***

- Longer delay not helping. 5 or 10 sec does the same
- Tested on Chrome,Safari,Opera ( with ip and with mdns ) Not working on any of the browsers on IOS.
- SameSite attribute made it worse
- httpOnly attribute did nothing

**EDIT2***

The problem was my getCookie method.
On Android and windows and every other possible OS and system the cookies comes like this:

```
language=HU; dark-theme=true; zone-grid=true; sessionID=FE0ED968-C246-4BCC-814E-6E49E
```

On IOS the cookies comes like this

```
sessionID=F04E13A7-0D26-4DD6-A444-814A5F3E7758; dark-theme=false; language=HU
```

My getCookie method was this:

```
boolean HsH_Server::getCookie(const char* name, const char* cookie, const char*& result) {
    if (name == nullptr || cookie == nullptr ||
        strlen(name) == 0 || strlen(cookie) == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    const char* position = strstr(cookie, name);
    if (position == nullptr) {
        return false;
    }

    // Calculate the start position after the name and '=' character.
    position += strlen(name) + 1;

    // Find the end position (either the next ';' or the end of the cookie string).
    const char* endPos = strchr(position, ';');
    if (endPos == nullptr) {
        // If there's no ';', it means this is the last cookie.
        endPos = cookie + strlen(cookie);
    }

    // Calculate the length of the cookie value.
    size_t length = endPos - position;

    // Set the result pointer to point to the start of the cookie value.
    result = position;

    return true;
}
```

I rewrote to use Strings so it become this

```
boolean HsH_Server::getCookie(String name, String cookie, String& result) {
    int position = cookie.indexOf(name);
    if (position == -1) {
        return false;
    }
    name += "=";
    int length = name.length();
    int startPos = position + length;
    int stopPos = cookie.indexOf(";", startPos);
    result = cookie.substring(startPos, stopPos);
    return true;
}
```

It is not really a solution yet because i try to avoid Strings. But the problem was in my getCookie() method.

Comment: Does anything change if you do not reload or move to a different page automatically, but make the user explicitly click a link instead? Apple is making increased efforts lately to better protect users from tracking across the web, so it is hard to say if this would fall into the bug or rather the feature category.

Comment: Your request to the backend does not appear to be cross-origin, so `SameSite` should not have any influence here. `httpOnly` might, perhaps - especially when it comes to user privacy and protecting it: Whether only the originating server, or _any_ client side script (3rd-party scripts) is able to read it, is a bit of a difference.

Comment: I added HttpOnly and SameSite attributes. If i have SameSite set to None it stops working on every browser. Including Chrome on Windows. If i leave HttpOnly it works on WIndows and Android but not on IOS.

Comment: The strange thing is that if i log in on IOS, it will not log me in first. But if i refresh the page after login and auto refresh or close and open it again, it logs in by sessionID.

Comment: I yet to try a really huge delay before refresh and see what happens.

Comment: Tested on Chrome,Safari,Opera ( with ip and with mdns ) Not working on any of the browsers on IOS

Comment: _"If i have SameSite set to None it stops working on every browser."_ - `SameSite=None` would also need the `Secure` flag (and the requests need to be made via HTTPS, not HTTP - can't tell if that is currently the case in your scenario.)

Comment: Yeah, it is http only

Comment: I got the problem. I edited my post

Comment: I have to rewrite my getCookie() method because it fails when the cookie in reverse order. I don't know why.

Comment: Rather then editing the question to include the solution, you should put that part into a self-answer - https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: It does not answer to my question correctly. I just found the problem but the answer is yet to be found. I have to write a proper function for getCookie() to use char arrays rather than Strings.

Comment: Ah, okay. The order in which you will get the name=value pairs for multiple cookies, should not be relied on. Not sure how exactly your current implementation is going wrong though, you appear to already check for the position where the name of the cookie starts, and then look for the next `;` or end of value, to determine the value for that cookie ... Might need a bit more in-depth debugging then.

Comment: Yeah, really strange. I still don't have the answer. I keep using the String version ( at least its working ) until i have time to figure it out!